# Is it possible to retrain googles inception model with one class?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, deep-learning

I would like to train this beautiful model to recognize only one type of images. To be clear at the end having the model capable of telling if the new image is part of that class or no. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep in mind is that when you want to recognize a "dog" for example you need to know what is NOT a "dog" as well. So your classification problem is a two class problem and not one class. Your two classes will be "My Type" and "Not My Type".

About retraining your model, yes it is possible. I guess you use a model pretrained on Imagenet Dataset. There is two cases : If the classification problem is close (for example if your "type" is a class from Imagenet) you can just replace your last layer (replace Fully connected 1x1000 by FC 1x2) and retrain on this layer. If the problem is not the same you may want to retrain more layers.

It also depends on the number of Samples you have for your retrain.

I hope it helps or clarifies your question.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your interest. I thoughtful in the same way too. I followed this guide ( https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#2 ) and I had, as classes, two folders, one with the object i wanted to classify and another with other pictures. The problem with this method is: how can i choose "Not My Type" pictures? Thank you in advance

Comment: It depends on what kind of images you expect your network to meet once it's trained.
Let's take an example, say I want to have a classifier to classify cell images and to tell me if it's a cancerous cell or a normal cell. Well I won't give it a cat or dog images since I don't expect my network to meet a dog image (nor a cat) even if a dog is not a cancerous cell.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to retrain googles inception model with one class?

**Yes**. Just remove the last layer, add a new layer with one (or two) nodes and train it on your new problem. This way you keep general features learned on the (probably bigger) image net dataset.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Do you have some tips about how to do that? I'm using Ubuntu 17.04. Thanks